# Split values into separate lines for each delimiter - batch

Tags: batch-file, split, delimiter

I'm trying to split the values of a csv file into separate lines using the delimiter=, as a point to split from. i.e.

```
#csv file 
video1,video2,video3
video4,video5,video6

#Preferred output:
video1,
video2,
video3,
ect....
```

So far I have:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=, " %%a in (input.csv) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^%%a^,>>output.csv
)
```

However I run into the issue of parameter %%a just being added as a string. How would I cause a split instead for each , and put the string onto a newline?

Comment: The caret symbols `^` in your `echo ^%%a^,` command have no effect; why have you added them?

Comment: I don't know....*cries*

Comment: In your code you can safely remove the `^` symbols. A caret is the escape character for the Windows Command Prompt, e. g., to echo a character like `>`, you need to write `echo >`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setLocal 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.csv) do (
 for %%i in (%%a) do echo %%i,>>output.csv
)
```

Each line is placed into `%%a` in turn.

Using the default list delimiters (space, comma, semicolon) the `%%i` for assigns each token in turn from the line in `%%a` to `%%i`

Comment: Brilliant! I was getting close, wasn't sure how to actually break into new lines. Thanks

Comment: I tested it on one line file (long one), and the output file contained only the first value

Comment: @soninob: the output will depend on the precise nature of the input. This version would match OP's specified data. Please raise your own question containing a representative sample of your data. As you say, you have one long line, so your sample should show just sufficient data to show your problem (eg `my_data,doesn't_work`) together with what the result is that you see from the routine and what you expected to see.

Answer (score 4):

This version can also handle empty columns and columns containing stuff like `*` or `?`.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.csv) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    echo reading line: !line!
    for /F "delims=" %%C in (""!line:^,^=^"^

"!"^") do (
        set "col=%%~C"
        echo   - !col!
    )
)
```

The trick is, that the ; will be replaced with `"<newline>"` and quotes are added to the front and end of the line.

`video1,,video3` will be changed to

```
"video1"  
""
"video3"
```

The `%%~C` removes the outer quotes, to retrieve the desired column content