# In batch split a string to new lines in file by delimiter

Tags: batch-file, split, substring

In batch I'm trying to split a string into substrings preferably based on a delimiter.

This example works but is there a better way to do this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-20 delims=:" %%a in (string.txt) do (
echo %%a& echo.%%b& echo.%%c& echo.%%d& echo.%%e& echo.%%f& echo.%%g& echo.%%h& echo.%%i& echo.%%j
echo.%%k& echo.%%l& echo.%%m& echo.%%n& echo.%%o& echo.%%p& echo.%%q& echo.%%r& echo.%%s& echo.%%t
) >substrings.txt
```

I have tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40384106/13515739) from Magoo which works for default delimiters but fails using colon:

```
@echo off
setLocal 
for /f "delims=:" %%a in (string.txt) do (
for %%i in (%%a) do echo %%i >>substrings.txt
)
```

I have also tried [this code](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429#p41035) from Aacini but it seems to fail using special characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=1
set "x=%string%"
set "x!i!=%x::=" & set /A i+=1 & set "x!i!=%"
set x >substrings.txt
```

An example %string% var or string.txt is:

```
Select project:/option:report name="Sustainability":option value="201":Huonville:/option:/report:report name="Energy and Water Management":option value="102":Cygnet:/option:/report:report name="Tree Management":option value="101":Cygnet:/option:/report:option disabled="disabled":/option:/select
```

I am trying to output %string% var or string.txt to substring.txt as follows:

```
Select project
/option
report name="Sustainability"
option value="201"
Huonville
/option
/report
report name="Energy and Water Management"
option value="102"
Cygnet
/option
/report
report name="Tree Management"
option value="101"
Cygnet
/option
/report
option disabled="disabled"
/option
/select
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `for /f`, you need to know how many tokens there are (and there is a limit for max tokens).

You need a plain `for` loop, but you can't choose, which delimiter should be used.

So replace every delimiter with a space. Be sure to have quotes around each "token" to take care of original spaces. To do this, put quotes around the whole string and replace the delimter `:` with `" "`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=Select project:/option:report name="Sustainability":option value="201":Huonville:/option:/report:report name="Energy and Water Management":option value="102":Cygnet:/option:/report:report name="Tree Management":option value="101":Cygnet:/option:/report:option disabled="disabled":/option:/select""

set "string=%string: =@%"
set "string="%string::=" "%"
(for %%a in (%string%) do (
  set "out=%%~a"  
  echo !out:@= !
))>out.txt
echo take a look at the modified string:
echo %string%
echo/
type out.txt
```

Another approach (just for academic reasons):

```
 @echo off
setlocal 
set "string=Select project:/option:report name="Sustainability":option value="201":Huonville:/option:/report:report name="Energy and Water Management":option value="102":Cygnet:/option:/report:report name="Tree Management":option value="101":Cygnet:/option:/report:option disabled="disabled":/option:/select"

call :recur %string%
goto :eof

:recur
rem echo loop with %*
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ("%*") do ( 
  echo %%a
  if not "%%~b" == "" call :recur %%b
  goto :eof
)
echo.
```

Note: there is a recursion limit (due to stack-size). It works with the given string, but may fail when the string contains more "tokens".

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I can output `string.txt` with space instead of colon `:` for delimiter but that then breaks the original spaces, which is why i figured using colon `:` would be better. But from what I'm understanding Stephan your code requires the colon `:` delimiter to wrap all tokens in surrounding quotes `" "` and the modified string is to be run again as a plain `for` loop. Is this correct? Maybe I should just stick with `echo.` lol

Comment: yes, you summarized it pretty well. See the last line of the first code to see the altered string to be parsed by `for`. `For` takes `alpha beta` as two "tokens", but `"alpha beta"` as just one (that's the trick used to keep the original spaces unchanged).

Comment: Stephan could you please also demonstrate how I can `echo` the altered string to new lines as I'm still getting a long (altered) string. The point of breaking the string into substrings is so that I can search using `for /f %%a in ('findstr "search" "substring.txt"')`

Comment: the "long altered string" is just to show you. See the output before. I changed my first code with a `find`.

Comment: The output is broken on spaces. It looks right in "long altered string" but if I try to use search or redirect output from `...echo %%~a) >substrings.txt` the tokens are broken.

Comment: I see, what you mean. I told you, batch is a bad choice for such tasks. I edited the first approach to take care of it. The second (recursive) one already worked as expected.

Comment: This solves the objective perfectly new lines are output to text. Stephan could you please look at the output from `...out=!out!)) | findstr "label value" >out.txt` I'm not sure if there is a way to reconstruct it back to token, or I guess I have to push the final `out.txt` through another `for /f` loop which is fine, I was just wondering if search could also work. Thanks mate

Comment: could theoretical be done without a file, but a lot of escaping and advanced programming tricks would be necessary, which means a simple change in the string could mess it up completely. Postprocessing the file (`for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('find "report name" out.txt') do echo %%~a`) is the easiest and safest way.

Comment: I've reposted a summary of this to dostips https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=62222#p62222 thanks again for your help Stephan.

Answer (score 1):

See @dbenham's AMAZING [`CERTUTIL`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57918#p57918) string replacement [technique](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57866#p57866). It works for any characters, even exclams`!`

```
@echo off
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set "B=^!"
set "C=^"
set ^"L=^
%===Line Feed===%
"
for /F "eol=N" %%C in ('wmic os get Name /value') do set "R=%%C" Carriage Return
set ^"E=!R!!L!" CRLF


>nul 2>&1 certutil -f -encodehex String.txt "%temp%\hex.txt" 4


pushd "%temp%"
>expand.txt (FOR /F "delims=" %%A in (hex.txt) do FOR %%B in (%%A) do (
    set "char=%%B"
    REM ! --> !B! ###
    set "char=!char:21=21 42 21!"
    REM ^ --> !C! ###
    set "char=!char:5e=21 43 21!"
    REM <CR> --> !R! ###
    set "char=!char:0a=21 4c 21!"
    REM <LF> --> !L! ###
    set "char=!char:0d=21 52 21!"


    REM : --> !R!!L! ###
    set "char=!char:3a=21 45 21!"
    echo(!char!
))


>nul 2>&1 certutil -f -decodehex expand.txt rawContent.txt
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (rawContent.txt) do set "modified=%%A"
del hex.txt expand.txt rawContent.txt
popd


>substring.txt (
echo(!modified!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary of what Stephan came up with.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p string=<"input.txt"
set "string=%string: =@%"
set "string="%string::=" "%"
(for %%a in (%string%) do (
  set "output=%%~a"  
  echo !output:@= !
))>output.txt
```

Set string or input text file (modify line 3).

`set /p string=<"input.txt"`

The delimiter in this example is colon [***:***] which follows after [***string:***] (modify line 5).

`set "string="%string::=" "%"`

If ***string*** or ***input.txt*** contains quotes ***%string%*** may need to be double quoted (modify line 3).

`for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (set string="%%a")`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (set string="%%a")
set "string=%string: =@%"
set "string="%string::=" "%"
(for %%a in (%string%) do (
  set "output=%%~a"  
  echo !output:@= !
))>output.txt
```